# EF6 keeps restoring non-existent stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I'm working in MVC 5 and using Entity Framework 6 (EF).  My project is DB first, so everything has been created directly through SSMS.  Whenever I update my model from the database, it won't delete a few stored procedures (SPs) which I deleted from the database a while back.  I can't find them in object explorer of SSMS, and I've even tried manually deleting them from the project in VS.  However, every time I regenerate my EF model (in VS), they just get recreated (in VS).

Why would this be happening if they don't even exist anymore?  It has to be stored somewhere in the project but I've ran through all the files in my EF project.

Here is how it is currently laid out.

In DB (Object Explorer (SSMS)):

- dbo.usp_one

ObjectResults in DB Context (VS):

- usp_one
- usp_two
- usp_three
- usp_four
- usp_five

in DB.tt (Result Classes) (VS):

- usp_one_Result.cs
- usp_two_Result.cs
- usp_three_Result.cs
- usp_four_Result.cs
- usp_five_Result.cs

What I've tried, is just doing a typical regenerate model from database.  When that didn't work, I attempted to manually delete the ObjectResults and Result Classes in the project.  After manually deleting them, I regenerated the model and they just came right back.

**How can I get these non-existent items removed from my project permanently?**

Comment: I take it someone already told you not to prefix your types / stored procedures with `sp_` as this is reserved by Microsoft?

Comment: @Igor usp <-- I know.  Let's ignore the naming schema for now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was to delete the individual model that I needed updated.  I did this through the EDMX diagram.  Just right click the header of the table/view you want to update and you'll see the options.  After that I just updated the model from the DB as I normally would and all was well.